# Using Post in Retrofit

Tags: java, android

Can you anyone help me giving good example on how to use retrofit for posting large data from my local DB to mysql server.

Currently I am using async-http API and strangely there is always memory error coming up. I am looking for better API that wont give memory error while uploading huge text of data.

This is my setup:

```
List<TextDetails> unTextList = dbvalue.getTextData();
    for (TextDetails td : unTextList)
    {
    String textID = td.getSerialNumber();
    String textSMS = td.getText();
    String textAddress = td.getFulladdress();
    String textDate = td.getFulldate();
    String textException = td.getExceptiontext();


    textDetailsBackUpDataOnline(textID , textSMS, textAddress, textDate, textException);
    }

    private void textDetailsBackUpDataOnline(final String textID ,
    String textSMS, String textAddress, String textDate, String textException)
    {
    final String uploadWebsite = url_backup_text_details;

    RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();

    requestParams.put("textSMS", textSMS);
    requestParams.put("textAddress", textAddress);
    requestParams.put("textDate", textDate);
    requestParams.put("textException", textException);

    Text_HttpClient.post(uploadWebsite, requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
    {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody)
    {
    Log.e("textID", "= how many times");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    });
    }
```

Text_HttpClient class has the following:

```
public class Text_HttpClient 
{
private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler)
{
client.get(url, params, responseHandler);
}

public static void post(String url, RequestParams requestParams, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler)
{
client.post(url, requestParams, responseHandler);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Write service interface:

```
public interface ArticleGetListService {
    @FormUrlEncoded // Request will have "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  MIME type
    @POST("/api/Article/ArticleGetList")
    public void getArticleList(@Field("LanguageCode") String languageCode,
                               @Field("CategoryId") String categoryId,
                               @Field("Token") String token,
                               Callback<ArticleViewPojo> response); //POJO: The json retrieved from the server is added to this class.
}
```

Here my Rest service requires 3 Parameters, change it as your need.

2) Write POJO for converting JSON returned from Rest Api into java class object so you can use data.

Just copy your JSON into [this site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/),  choose JSON source type, annotation as Gson. It will generate POJO for your JSON automatically.

3)On your Main Activity

```
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setEndpoint(baseUrl)
                .build();

        ArticleGetListService articleGetListService = restAdapter.create(ArticleGetListService.class);
        Callback<ArticleViewPojo> callback = new Callback<ArticleViewPojo>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ArticleViewPojo model, Response response) {
                //use model which is data returned to you
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                //handle error
            }
        };
        //START REST CALL
        articleGetListService.getArticleList(languageCode, categoryId, token, callback);
       //above parameters are those written in service interface at 1

//Whole Url is baseUrl+ArticleGetListService in above example
```

Comment: Hi, I am not receiving anything from Json I am sending data to mysql.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This totally helped me to solve upload issue. Thanks!